# Calculate tile coordinates in EPSG 4326

Tags: tiles, wmts

My goal is to be able to query cached tiles from a WMTS server using the EPSG4326 projection.

I would like to be able to use (1) the geographic coordinates of a point in degrees and a (2) zoom level (plus if required (3) the meta-information provided by the WMTS server), and obtain the (x,y) coordinates of the tile that contains my point.

For example, in EPSG3857, I can translate the coordinate (32.839833, -117.244648) at zoom level 13, corresponding to Mt Soledad in San Diego, to obtain the "tile coordinate" (3304,1428) using code provided on the internet (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Python). On online services I can retrieve the tile and verify that it contains the orginal point I was looking for:

https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/13/3304/1428
https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/World_Imagery/default/default028mm/13/3304/1428.jpg

I attempted the same thing on a EPSG4326 service. I published an image server on on a local ArcGIS server with cached tiles containing the same data, but this time using the EPSG 4326 projection. After, some poking around, I manually found the coordinates of my tile:

http://192.168.73.100/server/rest/services/imagery_sd_4326/ImageServer/tile/13/19750/15210

The scale and footprint of that tile are visibly different from the corresponding tile on arcgisonline. My questions are the following:

- What is the meaning of the scale parameters that I see in some of the descriptions of the EPSG coordinate system (for instance: https://www.linz.govt.nz/data/linz-data-service/guides-and-documentation/wgs-84-web-mercator-tile-scale-set-definition)
- In WMTS service pages, TileMatrixSet sections have attributes defined. Where can I find a complete list and description of these attributes. (for instance: ScaleDenominator, TopLeftCorner, MatrixWidth, MatrixHeight). I assume that these parameters have to do with tile layout.
- In general, how can I use the information in the WMTS service page to calculate a tile coordinate containing a given GPS point.

Comment: You almost certainly need to start by reading the WMTS specification - https://www.ogc.org/standards/wmts